# UIView with UIButtons not showing up prior to click or rotate

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, custom-controls

I've been banging my head with this issue for the last two days. Googled a lot but wasn't able to find the answer yet, so I decided to request some help here. Let's see if I get any luck.

I'm coding a reusable control that consists of an `UIView` with a variable number of customized `UIButtons`. I implemented `initWithFrame`:, `initWithCoder`: and `drawRect`: where the buttons (which are built prior to drawing) are actually added to the view. Everything is done programmatically since the `UIButton` content should be supplied when using the control, so there's no XIB for this `UIView`.

This `UIView`, let's call it `CustomizableBarButton` is then used in an `UIViewController`, let's call it `MyTestViewController` with a view on it, let's call it `customizableBarButtonView`.

`MyTestViewController`'s GUI was set on IB where an `UIView` was tied to `customizableBarButtonView` (the class was matching accordingly).

`MyTestViewController`'s is a pretty standard class except for the `viewWillAppear`: that initializes the buttons and passes them to the `CustomizableBarButton` along with some other options.

The issue is that everything works perfectly...except for the first time!

I mean, when I run the app on the simulator (I haven't tried it on the iPhone yet but I strongly believe that it's not an hardware issue) the `MyTestViewController` shows the `customizableBarButtonView` background but not the buttons. Now when you click on the place where a button should be all the buttons suddenly appear!

I'm puzzled since the `CustomizablebarButton` drawRect: runs before the strange "click n'appear" effect and the buttons are actually added to the subview.

Another hint that my help: if you don't click on the buttons (so you still got no buttons yet) but rotate the device they will also appear as if by magic!

It is probably something very simple but I'm missing it and I'm going nuts...

Can someone lend a hand on this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you're adding the buttons in `drawRect:`.  Don't do that.  You need to add the buttons in your init methods.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! The question is that my init methods don't know about the buttons. The buttons are created from a NSArray of a data object that describes the buttons (image, title, etc...). The NSArray is an observed property so the property is set *AFTER* the MyTestViewController calls the init method of CustomButtonBar.

Comment: Then add your buttons as soon as you observe changes to the array.  Don't wait until drawRect.

Comment: Many thanks, Rob! You're a life saver! It worked perfectly! Just seeking to understand the problem: you should I shy away from drawRect:? Isn't it Apple's recommended way of "populating" a custom UIView?

Comment: `drawRect:` is for drawing the view's own content, not for adding subviews.  If your view is responsible for changing the color of a pixel on the screen, that code should go in `drawRect:`.  If some other view is responsible, that other view needs to be in the view hierarchy before the system starts sending `drawRect:` messages.

Comment: _"drawRect: is for drawing the view's own content, not for adding subviews"_ - Perfect! This was what I was looking for! Many thanks for everything, Rob!